# More than one file cannot use an automatically generated guid unless a versioned file is the keypath and the other files are unversioned. Error

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.8

I have a C# solution with 4 projects there is only a single dll created for 3 of the projects and an exe from the main project.  I've never used WIX but followed the simple example and was able to compile my code but only the .exe is deployed.  I've tried modifing to add the other projects:

```
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Source="$(var.MedusaPerfApp.TargetPath)" />
        <File Source="$(var.CustomClassLibrary.TargetPath)" />
        <File Source="$(var.CustomControls.TargetPath)" />
        <File Source="$(var.MultitaskingFramework.TargetPath)" />
    </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   3   The Component/@Guid attribute's value '*' is not valid for this component because it does not meet the criteria for having an automatically generated guid. Components with more than one file cannot use an automatically generated guid unless a versioned file is the keypath and the other files are unversioned. This component has a non-keypath file that is versioned. Create multiple components to use automatically generated guids.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says: `Create multiple components to use automatically generated guids.` Put each File element in its own Component element.

Comment: I had tried doing it as a new fragment and group but that didn't work.  Tired what you recommended and that worked.  Many thanks!

Comment: The "one file per component" practice is almost always the way to go. For a detailed explanation, see [Organizing Applications into Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370561(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: That link doesn't actually say that but this one does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368269(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and found a solution without having to wrap each file in a component tag. All you have to do is add a Guid to the component.

```
<Component Id="appComponent" Guid="6263db4e-4c67-4adc-9ef1-e1caef798331">
```

[Here](https://www.rhyous.com/2010/10/15/wix-creating-an-msi-to-deploy-multiple-files/) is an example you can follow